# EscapeDataString can't be null

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am using MVC, I'm trying to create a account from MVC, but I want it to set the username of a user to their steam nickname, by only providing their steamid in the create view.

```
public string GetUsernameFromId(string Steamid)
{
    string steamid2 = Steamid.ToString();
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v2/?key=steamapihide&steamids=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(steamid2) + "&format=xml");

    string UserNames = (string)doc.Descendants("personaname").FirstOrDefault();

    return UserNames;
}
```

In the controller I have this:

```
  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create(string Tradelink, string password, string Steamid)
    {
        Balance accBalance = bctrl.CreateonCreateAccount();

        SteamAccount acc = new SteamAccount
        {
            SteamId = Steamid,
            UserName = GetUsernameFromId(Steamid),
            Password = password,
            accountbalance = accBalance,
            TradeLink = Tradelink

        };
        Create(acc);
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(SteamAccount acc)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Balance accountbalance = bctrl.CreateonCreateAccount();
            acc.accountbalance = accountbalance;
            acc.UserName = GetUsernameFromId(acc.SteamId);
            foreach (var item in acc.AccountSkins)
            {
                sctrl.CreateonCreateAccount(item);
            }
            AccountRepo.Insert(acc);
            AccountRepo.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(acc);
        }
    }
```

this is my model class

```
namespace CSGO_MVC.Models

{
    public class SteamAccount
    {
        [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string SteamId { get; set; }

    public Balance accountbalance { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Provide Username", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide password", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public bool UserStatus { get; set; }

    public string TradeLink { get; set; }

    public List<Skin> AccountSkins { get; set; }
```

And the error I'm getting is that

> Steamid can't be null in the GetUsernameFromId method

when I try to run this.

Comment: You probably are not getting the steam ID from your request. Check your path settings, check the request URL and check the content of your variables in a debugger. Since we don't have all of this information, there is not much we can do here.

Comment: FYI, you've included your steam API key in the question.

Comment: What does the URL for your create method look like?

Comment: Regarding @ChrisPickford's spot; you may want to remove this post permanently to hide this info (or better, just get a new key): https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62095/199916

Comment: @JohnLBevan localhost/SteamAccCrud/Create

Comment: @FarzadHenareh That may be the issue; normally with an MVC app you'd pass the values on the URL; e.g. https://localhost/SteamAccCrud/Create/myTradelink/myPassword/mySteamId